# TTTAttributedLabel links not clickable after adding a UITapGestureRcognizer on the label

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uitapgesturerecognizer, tttattributedlabel

I have a `TTTAttributedLabel` to detect the URLs contained in my label, and now I also want to detect `@menions`.
To do so, I've added a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the label and on each tap I'm checking if the tapped word starts with @, etc.

My custom logic works properly, but now the URL detection of the `TTTAttributedLabel` is broken. I've tried setting the delegate to my UITapGestureRecognizer and overriding

```
override func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

but the URL clicks are still not being detected. Any idea of how I can have both functionalities on my label?

EDIT, Some of my code:

The UITapGestureRcognizer is initialized as such:

```
commentLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true;
let labelTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(labelTapped(_:)))
labelTap.delegate = self
commentLabel.addGestureRecognizer(labelTap)
```

My tap function is the following:

```
@objc func labelTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        // Find the character that was tapped...
        let textLabel = sender.view as? UILabel
        let tapLocation = sender.location(in: textLabel)

        // init text storage
        var textStorage: NSTextStorage? = nil
        if let attributedText = textLabel?.attributedText {
            textStorage = NSTextStorage(attributedString: attributedText)
        }
        let layoutManager = NSLayoutManager()
        textStorage?.addLayoutManager(layoutManager)

        // init text container
        let textContainer = NSTextContainer(size: CGSize(width: textLabel?.frame.size.width ?? 0.0, height: (textLabel?.frame.size.height ?? 0.0) + 100))
        textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0
        textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = textLabel?.numberOfLines ?? 0
        if let lineBreakMode = textLabel?.lineBreakMode {
            textContainer.lineBreakMode = lineBreakMode
        }

        layoutManager.addTextContainer(textContainer)

        // Get the character that was tapped
        let characterIndex = layoutManager.characterIndex(
            for: tapLocation,
            in: textContainer,
            fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints: nil)

        // Now find the word that was tapped
        let word = textLabel?.text?.getWordFromCharacteratIndex(characterIndex) // Another custom function I've built that returns the word form a character

        // And match it with a mentioned user
        // Some code to match the word with my mentions pattern
        // ...........
    }
```

Comment: Can you please show code from tap function?

Comment: I've added the tap function in my question.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the other label where you can detect #hashtags, @usernames & hyperlinkes

https://github.com/optonaut/ActiveLabel.swift

Comment: Looks like a great library, that does what I need, thank you :) I'll consider it in the future if we decide to replace the old `TTTAttributedLabel`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The UITapGestureRecognizer was cancelling the tap event after it was recognized, so by setting `labelTap.cancelsTouchesInView = false` to my `UITapGestureRegognizer`, the touch even gets delivered to both callbacks. And I don't even need to implement the `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer` delgate method, as the `TTTAttributedLabel` is using touch events instead of UITapGestureRecognizer` for its URL detection.